# Count operation not working on aggregated IgniteDataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I am working with Apache Spark and Apache Ignite. I have a spark dataset which I wrote in Ignite using following code

```
dataset.write()
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .format(FORMAT_IGNITE())
                .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), "ignite-server-config.xml")
                .option(OPTION_TABLE(), "CUSTOM_VALUES")
                .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS(), "ID")
                .save();
```

And I am reading it again to perform group by operation which will be pushed to Ignite.

```
  Dataset igniteDataset = sparkSession.read()
                .format(FORMAT_IGNITE())
                .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), "ignite-server-config.xml")
                .option(OPTION_TABLE(), "CUSTOM_VALUES")
                .load();


        RelationalGroupedDataset idGroupedData = igniteDataset.groupBy(customized_id);

        Dataset<Row> result = idGroupedData.agg(count(id).as("count_id"),
                count(fid).as("count_custom_field_id"),
                count(type).as("count_customized_type"),
                count(val).as("count_value"), count(customized_id).as("groupCount"));
```

Now, I want to get the number of rows returned by groupby action. So, I am calling count() on dataset as`result.count();`

When I do this, I get following exception.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM (SELECT  FROM CUSTOM_VALUES GROUP[*] BY CUSTOMIZED_ID) TABLE1 "; expected "., (, USE, AS, RIGHT, LEFT, FULL, INNER, JOIN, CROSS, NATURAL, ,, SELECT"; SQL statement:
SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM (SELECT  FROM CUSTOM_VALUES GROUP BY CUSTOMIZED_ID) table1 [42001-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:217)
```

Other functions such as `show(), collectAsList().size();` works.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your example against the last community version 8.7.5 of GridGain that is the opensource version of Gridgain based on Ignite 2.7.0 sources with a subset of additional fixes (https://www.gridgain.com/resources/download).

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You should set the path to client configuration file.");

        String configPath = args[0];

        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> igniteDataset = session.read()
                .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE())                  //Data source
                .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(), "Person")         //Table to read.
                .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), configPath) //Ignite config.
                .load();

        RelationalGroupedDataset idGroupedData = igniteDataset.groupBy("CITY_ID");

        Dataset<Row> result = idGroupedData.agg(count("id").as("count_id"),
                count("city_id").as("count_city_id"),
                count("name").as("count_name"),
                count("age").as("count_age"),
                count("company").as("count_company"));

        result.show();

        session.close();
    }
}
```

Here are the maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
        <artifactId>gridgain-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spark</artifactId>
        <version>8.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the cache configuration:

```
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="Person"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="sqlSchema" value="PUBLIC"/>

                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <property name="keyType" value="PersonKey"/>
                            <property name="valueType" value="PersonValue"/>
                            <property name="tableName" value="Person"/>

                            <property name="keyFields">
                                <list>
                                    <value>id</value>
                                    <value>city_id</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>

                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                                    <entry key="city_id" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                                    <entry key="name" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    <entry key="age" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                                    <entry key="company" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                </map>
                            </property>

                            <property name="aliases">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="id" value="id"/>
                                    <entry key="city_id" value="city_id"/>
                                    <entry key="name" value="name"/>
                                    <entry key="age" value="age"/>
                                    <entry key="company" value="company"/>
                                </map>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Using Spark 2.3.0 that is only supported for ignite-spark dependency I have next result on my test data:

Data:

```
ID,CITY_ID,NAME,AGE,COMPANY,
4,1,Justin Bronte,23,bank,
3,1,Helen Richard,49,bank,
```

Result:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+
|CITY_ID|count_id|count_city_id|count_name|count_age|count_company|
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+
|      1|       2|            2|         2|        2|            2|
+-------+--------+-------------+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Also, this code could be fully applied to Ignite 2.7.0.

Comment: as I mentioned above in the question, result.show() works fine, the problem is with result.count().